# border-image transparent stripes in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scale, border-image

I'm using CSS3 border-image in combination with scale3d transformation. Works nice, except in Google Chrome. Chrome shows some transparent stripes between the border-image tiles where the background is clipping through.

I made a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="frame scale">
Hello Hello<br/>
Hello Hello<br/>
Hello Hello<br/>
Hello Hello<br/>
</div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}
div{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 170px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale3d(3.1,3.1,1);
}

.frame{
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 38px 28px 37px 18px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://picload.org/image/rgrocaia/roll13_t1_small1_25.png) 38 28 37 18 stretch;
       -moz-border-image: url(https://picload.org/image/rgrocaia/roll13_t1_small1_25.png) 38 28 37 18 stretch;
         -o-border-image: url(https://picload.org/image/rgrocaia/roll13_t1_small1_25.png) 38 28 37 18 stretch;
}
```

I also made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/kd7sz0s5/1/

The problem seems to have to do with the scale3d command. Because the stripes are disappearing when I set the scale3d value to an even number (e.g. scale3d(3,3,1)).

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Pixel rounding I'd guess.